# Reusing CHECK CONSTRAINTS

Tags: sql-server, constraints, rules

In SQL Server assuming one has columns that need to have the same data type is it possible to define a check constraint at the table (or database level) and apply that to a column when you define it?

As in this (contrived) example:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblAuditTrail
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DecimalNumber
CHECK (DecimalColumn LIKE '^\-?\d+\.\d+$')
GO
```

How now can you associate that with one or more columns having created it at the table level or is the answer to this to use a RULE viz.

```
CREATE RULE RU_Decimal
AS
@value LIKE '^\-?\d+\.\d+$'
GO
```

I know that the example is contrived and one would use a decimal column for decimal values but assume, because of a poor design choice, that this was an nchar column and you wanted to enforce some constraints on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although rules do meet your requirements, they are now deprecated in favour of plain old check constraints.  It wouldn't be a good idea to use rules if you think the database may need to be moved to future versions of SQL Server.  See the "important" message at the top of the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx.

You can get some reuse by using a user defined function and call it in all the check constraints but you will still need to explicitly define the check constraints on all columns where it applies.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsDecimal(@input varchar(max))
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @value LIKE '^\-?\d+\.\d+$'
        RETURN 1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0
END
GO 

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblAuditTrail     
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DecimalNumber     
    CHECK (dbo.IsDecimal(DecimalColumn) = 1)     
GO
```

Comment: Daniel,

Many thanks for that. It seems to be a pity about rules being deprecated but that's life in IT I guess :-)

I will take and adapt your suggestion - many thanks!

Comment: This would work, but the performance of scalar UDFs is terrible.

Comment: @A-K It's 2022 now, and SQL Server can inline many UDFs for zero overhead (I assume this also applies to inlining in `CHECK` constraints too) - but you are right in that running any kind of `SELECT` query in a UDF used by a `CHECK` constraint can potentially ruin your DBA's day - but at least it's still better than using `TRIGGER` objects!

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint is a type constraint.

With SQL, you can deal with this situation through user-defined types, where your "reuse" is materialised by declaring multiple columns to be of this type,

or you must repeat the type constraint as a CHECK constraint for each individual column.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to associated a check constraint with a custom type.  It certainly is possible to use a CLR type but that is often not an option and certainly impacts performance.

Comment: Erwin

I don't really think so as all a UDT does is redefine an already existing type with a more suitable name or length viz:

sp_addtype birthday, datetime, 'NULL';

OR

sp_addtype N'CustomerName', nvarchar (20), not null